# Create instance in for loop and pass reference to thread (also created in the loop)

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

So I have the following class (modified to be easier to understand):

```
class MyClass
{
   private List<OtherClass> objects;
   private List<Thread> threads;


   public void Create(int number)
   {
      for(int i =0; i < number; i ++)
      {
         OtherClass obj = new();
         objects.Add(obj);
         Thread th = new(() =>
         {
            
             while(true)
             {
               obj.DoStuff();
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
             }
           
         });

         threads.Add(th);
      }

      foreach(Thread th in threads)
            th.Start();
   }
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I use the variable obj in each thread? Will it keep the reference to the object I created inside the loop?
2. Will this cause problems with the list? Should I add a lock inside the thread? Or perhaps create a method that will access the list in a thread-safe manner?

I thought of having a variable inside the for loop that will be used as an index in the thread (to access the list). The variable would be declared inside the loop and use the value of i.

For it to be thread safe, I thought of using lock either inside the thread or inside a method used to access the list.

I did not test this as I didn't complete other parts of the code that are needed for the program to run.

Comment: Normal lists are not thread-safe. [Others are](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/). If you did not test it, the bare minimum is to test it by yourself and _then_ ask here.

Comment: You are asking some very basic questions. My suggestion is to spend some time and study multithreading systematically. Here is a good online resource: [Threading in C# - BASIC SYNCHRONIZATION - Thread Safety](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Thread_Safety) by Joseph Albahari. Then, after reading the theory, come back and ask more specific/nuanced questions about things that are still unclear.

Comment: Maybe the better question would be if this is the way to go for what you need the code to do. What would _that_ be?

Comment: `Objects` here are created and added to a list regardless of any synchronization issues. Also, `Thread`s are created and added to the respective list without synchronization issues because both of which is done synchronously. The threads themselves are started _after the fact_. None of the threads is using _shared_ resources.